# HID Compliant TouchScreen for OS X 10.6

Tags: snow-leopard, touchscreen

Does anyone know of an HID-compliant touch screen that will work straight out of the box with Max OS X 10.6 without requiring any drivers to be installed?

Comment: Based on the lack of reply, maybe you should take a different approach. What is wrong with installing 300 drivers?

Comment: The problem with installing a 3rd party driver is that it is something else that we need to maintain. Say if OS X updates and suddenly the driver doesn't work anymore, we will have to fix it on 300 machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google found a couple of possibilities; I haven't tried them myself:

- [NextWindow - Touchscreen 2700](http://www.nextwindow.com/products/2700.html)
- [Planar Touch - Touchscreen LCD Monitor - PT1710mx 17" Monitor](http://www.planartouch.com/products/pt1710mx/)

There's the [Wacom Cintiq](http://www.wacom.com/cintiq/); while I believe they need drivers I'm sure they'd be available close to day & date.

And an entirely different approach to take might be the [Axiotron Modbook](http://www.axiotron.com/index.php?id=modbook).

Comment: Thanks Dori, these screens look pretty good. We've actually written our own driver for a touch screen now, but if we don't use that then we will definitely check these out.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be happy with an HID-compliant touchscreen running another OS (or OS X with drivers installed), and then a full-screen VNC to your driver-less OS X machine? You might not be able to tell the difference.

Comment: That's not an option sorry as we need to deploy ~300 machines with such a touch screen.